# Linux ioport.h and memblock.h header files missing

Tags: linux, header, kernel

At [this link](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/linux/memblock.h) (Linus Torvalds' GitHub) you will find some Linux header files like `memblock.h` and `ioport.h`.

I'm confused because I think that these files are supposed to be kernel headers; however, I can't find most of them in my current Linux (I'm using Debian with the kernel 4.9.0). Can any one tell me why I can't find them, please?

Answer (score 0):

Debian Stretch : memblock.h and ioport.h are in e.g. the package `linux-headers-4.9.0-2-common`

Package : https://packages.debian.org/stretch/linux-headers-4.9.0-2-common

File list : https://packages.debian.org/stretch/all/linux-headers-4.9.0-2-common/filelist

Comment: Thank you. And please what do you mean by Debian Stretch ? I'm running kali linux and i can't find these headers.

Comment: Quote : »» I'm using Debian with the kernel 4.9.0 «« : That's Debian 9 Stretch. The clone = Kali is not meant to be used as ordinary OS. Hence all the missing packages. Kali is meant for forensics / security only. For all other tasks, please use a real OS.

Comment: Ok Thank you again Sir. After some time i found that not all linux distriutions contain this files, oracle linux is one of them.